# Goblins kidnapped a child, got caught in a cage. How can I strip him?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In *Dwarf Fortress* (Steam), the goblins are inside my fort, underground. I have three: its cage built in a prison, its cage in a dump pile, its cage built outside of a zone. I have used the zone dump tool on the cages, and then gone into the cage UI to remove the cage itself from being dumped.

I have tried using a custom job to only haul refuse; that dwarf stood around doing nothing. I have tried making only hauler dwarves, but nothing. If I leave the cage either marked for dumping or not, but with the items on the goblin still marked for dumping, the unbuilt cage gets moved to the dumping pile, but none of the items leave the cage in either scenario.

I have dfhack; I have tried using stripcagged all on those ids to list everything and then autodump. Autodump does not seem to notice that they are marked; I have done this on built and non-built cages. I have been able to mark something else as dump and then move that with autodump, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I recall building a "pit of doom" where caged baddies were released through a hole some 10+ levels down and ending with a splat on a spike trap, not sure how I did it, only that it's quite possible and not that hard. So I'd have a long line of caged baddies waiting for their turn down the hole - you can place the cage with something inside like any piece of furniture I believe.

Comment: If the gobbo has a child in their bag then I'm not sure what would happen to the child after such an execution though. Better just release it and have some armed squad club the goblin to death if you wish to save the child.

Comment: Im not sure about the details but I do remember that when invaders show up and I give them cause to reconsider, the goblinite they drop tends to be forbidden. Any chance the stuff the caged goblins have on them is forbidden too? That would prevent dumping it.